# Pass variable within json payload in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, variable, escape-characters, json

In the following scenario, which is the way to pass `${MY_ENV_VAR}` in the payload?

I will have to escape:

a) the single quotes of the payload

b) the double quotes of the value of the `text` json field

I need `${MY_ENV_VAR)` to be interpolated of course.

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMAND=${MY_ENV_VAR}    

curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel": "#alerts", "username": "k8s-cronjobs-bot", "text": "Command ${MY_ENV_VAR} run with success", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}' ${SLACK_WEBHOOK}
```

Comment: You are right, I fixed this

Comment: Can you use the `jq` command?

Comment: Any suggestions how to go about it? You can post it as answer so that I also accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `jq`:

```
$ payload='{"channel": "#alerts", "username": "k8s-cronjobs-bot", "text": "", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}'
$ MY_ENV_VAR='"foo"'
$ echo "$payload" | jq --arg cmd "$MY_ENV_VAR" '.text = "Command " + $cmd + " run with success"'
{
  "channel": "#alerts",
  "username": "k8s-cronjobs-bot",
  "text": "Command \"foo\" run with success",
  "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"
}
```

So your script would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMAND=${MY_ENV_VAR}    
payload='{"channel": "#alerts", "username": "k8s-cronjobs-bot", "text": "", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}'
payload=$(echo "$payload" | jq -r --arg cmd "$COMMAND" '.text = "Command " + $cmd + " run with success"')
curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload=$payload"  "${SLACK_WEBHOOK}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, use `printf` to help with the mix of quotes:

```
printf -v payload '{"channel": "#alerts", "username": "k8s-cronjobs-bot", "text": "Command %s run with success", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}' "$MY_ENV_VAR"
curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload=$payload" "$SLACK_WEBHOOK"
```